# Finding tuples with exactly 1 matching pair and rest unique values

Tags: pattern-matching

I couldn't manage to find a solution this.

I'm not very experienced with mathemathica, so the solution might be quite simple, I don't know.

I have this non sorted set of tuples:

```
Tuples[{Range[1,4], Range[1, 6], Range[1,8], Range[1, 12], Range[1,20]}]
```

That represent dice events for 5 dices with a different amount of sides.

**Now to the problem:**

I'm trying to pattern match the case where there is exactly 1 matching pair of values in a tuple, and the rest of the values are unique

I've started to write a pattern matching function like this:

```
pairQ[{__, x_, x_, x_, ___} := False;
```

But using this method to account for every case would need A LOT of lines, surely there must be a much simpler way.

**So my question is: 
How can I efficiently find tuples from this set of length 5 tuples that have 2 values that are equal, rest unique?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given

```
tuples = Tuples[{Range[1,4], Range[1, 6], Range[1,8], Range[1, 12], Range[1,20]}]

Select[tuples, Length[Union[#]] == 4 &]
```

will give you the required answer in no time at all.

Comment: Excellent, thank you for a nice and quick answer.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that I'm a bit late here, but there's a solution using your own method of pattern matching:

```
Cases[data,{OrderlessPatternSequence[___,___,x_,x_]}]
```

`OrderlessPatternSequence` is a pattern specially designed for similar cases where people want to ignore the order of elements in a sequence. And in your case, you want to ignore the order between two `___` and two `x_`, so this will be optimal!